# How to get model name from array in cakephp/php

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to get Model-name from particular array values.my demo code is below

```
Array
(
    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ObjectTypeLineNo] => 1
                    [ActionType] => 
                    [LineNo] => 1
                )

        )

    [TaxConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ObjectTypeLineNo] => 1
                    [ActionType] => 
                    [LineNo] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

In my demo code it contain two model name CodeConfiguration,TaxConfiguration.I want this model name directly .so please suggest me solution.

Comment: simple foreach, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($array as $name => $value){
    echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer you have already got, you can also get array of this type of model by using `array_keys` function of php.

```
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

You can use this array as such, or you can use foreach on this array if you want individual model name.